# How do I access NSUserDefaults from several different views?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

If we are using `NSUserDefaults` to store a data, is it possible to access this data from a different view of the same project?

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't it be? (I appreciate this probably isn't a very useful answer, but the question is pretty unspecific.)

Comment: i have two views. first view display the contents of second view..in second view is settings view..when we enter the data to text field it display on first view..

Answer (score 4):

You can access the same NSUserDefaults instance from anywhere in your code. Use

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

to access it anywhere within your application.

Comment: Of course, NSUserDefaults is entirely the wrong answer for typical data flow in an app

Comment: if you want to use the User Defaults it maybe better  to use the bindings  in IB for what you are doing. But I think what  bbum might be referring to is Core data, which maybe ideal for the data flow you are talking about

Comment: That said, NSUserDefaults really should be used for storing small amounts of settings information. Use a file or database for large amounts of data (Core Data or not).